# Why codium (vscode fork) doesn't autoclose quotes?

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code

this is my first time using codium (vscode fork) after using atom for a while, I have installed several bash extension to enhance my shell scripting adventure, but I found that I'm unable to auto close the quotes. I have set autoclosing settings to always.

[image]

Below is screencap of the problem I occurred.

[image]

Can anyone help me solve this problem? I want it to be auto closed.

Comment: Which extensions did you install specifically? Details like this should definitely be included.

Comment: This behavior also occurred without extension

Comment: That's obvious. You're adding extensions to support language/syntax features. Most languages aren't supported too well by default, including bash.